# Slider images with dynamic width and height

Tags: html, css

I want to incorporate a rotating slider into my website but in order to have it occupy the whole screen on different devices mobile/desktop it needs to have a `width:100%` which makes the image not visible. I'm using the code from this library http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/rotating-slideshow-jquery-css3/ and I've setup a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/9mmzf7wh/1/

I've tried setting the `width:auto` and `width:100%`

Comment: The images aren't showing in your fiddle because they're being blocked at JSFiddle. You'll see 403 errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I made quite a few changes, but the gist of it is absolute positioning of `#slideShow` and the removal of a bunch of margin and/or padding statements that you had in place.

```
 #slideShowContainer {
    background: pink;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 70%;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#slideShow {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:100;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #111;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #111;
    z-index: 1;
}
#slideShow ul {
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9mmzf7wh/2/)**